Different expansion w.r.t two equivalent asymptotic sequences
Let $\phi_{n}(x)$ and $\varphi_{n}(x)$ be 2 sequences of real functions defined on ${x:0<|x-x_0|<a}$ which are asymptotic sequences as $x\to x_0$. Suppose $\phi_n = \varphi_n$ as$x\to x_0$, and that for some $a_n$ we have:
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \phi_n$$
Does there necessarily exist $b_n$ s.t.
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \varphi_n$$
(Hint: consider setting:
$$\varphi_0 = \phi_0$$
and
$$\varphi_n = \frac{\phi_{n-1}\phi_{n}}{\phi_{n-1} + \phi_{n}}$$
This is an asymptotic sequence and $\phi_n = \varphi_n$.'=' above are all asymptotic equivalence signs)
My attempt: I tried many choices of $\phi_n$ e.g. $x^n,x^{n^2}, e^{\frac{1}{n}x}$, but none of them worked. I guess if there exists $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \varphi_n$, then $a_n = b_n$ for all $n$ since $\varphi_n = \frac{\phi_n}{1+\frac{\phi_n}{\phi_{n-1}}}$. But I do not know how to give a counter example. Could someone help me please? Any help is greatly appreciated.
